# Adding random numbers to the arguments of a sum of cosines

Tags: random

This is probably really a simple question.

I would like to plot a sum of cosines with increased argument and for each cosine in sum I would like to add random value:

```
Plot[Sum[Cos[n*x + RandomReal[{0, 2 Pi}]], {n, 100}], {x, -10, 10}]
```

However it seems to me that the program, while making a plot, generates a new random number for each x-point plotted. Therefore, even for single cosine (`Plot[Cos[x + RandomReal[{0, 2*Pi}]], {x, -10, 10}]` ) I get a completely noisy graph of random cosine values.

I would be very grateful if somebody can tell me what to do to prevent the program from generating new random numbers at each x-point.

Comment: Just compute the random offset once: `With[{r = RandomReal[{0, 2 Pi}]}, Plot[Cos[x + r], {x, -10, 10}]]`

Comment: Thank you for answer. I tried it before, but then the problem is that i have the same random number for each cosine in my sum. And i would like to generate a new one for each (but not for each x when plotting).

Comment: Generate as many as you need: `With[{r = RandomReal[{0, 2 Pi}, 10]}, Plot[Total[Cos[Range[10] x + r]] // Evaluate, {x, -10, 10}]]`

Answer (score 2):

J.M. has answered the question in the comments. This is to get that answer (slightly edited) on record in a more visible form. For 10 terms, we get

```
SeedRandom[42];
  With[{n = 10},
    With[{r = RandomReal[{0, 2 Pi}, n]}, 
      Plot[Total[Cos[Range[n] x + r]], {x, -10, 10}]]]
```

[image: plot1]

For a 100 terms, which is what the OP asked for, the plot must be stretched out to see the details better.

```
SeedRandom[42];
  With[{n = 100},
    With[{r = RandomReal[{0, 2 Pi}, n]}, 
      Plot[Total[Cos[Range[n] x + r]], {x, -10, 10},
        AspectRatio -> 1/5,
        ImageSize -> Full]]]
```

[image: plot2]